# Xamarin.Android -> WebView -> Not opening Upload or Take Image Option

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, cross-platform

I have a website that when I open it using a regular brownser on the mobile, I can use the upload image or take a photo option, but when I access it inside an app developed in Xamarin.Android (native view approach) it wont open these options. Should I add some extra code to make it use the intent responsable for shoe the user those options?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some function in HTML5 can not be called in Android `WebView` for example:

`<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">`

it can call the native camera in the browser but it can not call the camera in `WebView`.

As a workaround you can use javascript interface to call android native fucntion.

For example：

1. Register and export your javacript object to the `WebView`

   ```
       WebView wv1 = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
       string fileUrl = "file:///android_asset/HTML5_Demo.html";
       wv1.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
       wv1.AddJavascriptInterface(new MyJSInterface(this), "wx");
   ```

   defined `MyJSInterface` to call camera:

   ```
   class MyJSInterface : Java.Lang.Object
   {
       Context context;

       public MyJSInterface(Context context)
       {
           this.context = context;
       }
       [Export]
       [JavascriptInterface]
       public void CallCamera()
       {
           Toast.MakeText(context, "Hello from C#", ToastLength.Short).Show();
           Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
           context.StartActivity(intent);
       }
   }
   ```
2. `wx` is the export object to the `WebView` you can get the object form the html page:

   `<div>
       <button onClick="window.wx.CallCamera()">call camera</button>
   </div>`

When you click the button you can call the native camera： 
[image]

**Note: remember to add Mono.Android.Export dll**

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for you suggestion, but I would like to open that default android window with options ("Camera", "File Manager", "Gallery").

Comment: Try to google how to use `Intent.CreateChooser`. And use it in the `Callcamera()` function.

Comment: Hi @MikeMa, I tried this approach and got to make the camera working but assigning the image (saved from image capture) to the file input element is not possible, i.e.: $('input[type="file"]').val(filenameHere); <-- is not going to work.

Comment: Is this statement still true in 2020? "it can call the native camera in the browser but it can not call the camera in WebView"